# In a TypeScript interface, is it possible to limit the keys in one property to the values of another property?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Consider the following TypeScript interface:

```
interface Foo {
  list: string[];
  obj: { [index: string]: string; };
}
```

Is there a way to specify the types so that that the keys in `obj` must be one of the values in `list`?

For example, the following would be valid:

```
class Bar implements Foo {
  list = ["key1", "key2"]
  obj = {"key1": "value1"}
}
```

However, the following would be a compile error:

```
class Bar implements Foo {
  list = ["key1", "key2"]
  // COMPILE ERROR
  // "some-other-key" is not in list
  obj = {"some-other-key": "value1"}
}
```

I've tried to limit the type of `obj` using `keyof` and Lookup Types, but have not been successful.

Comment: No, you must know allowed keys at compile time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed `list: string[]` because I assume that you don't really need it at runtime. This solution works at compile time:

```
interface Foo<T extends string[]> {
  obj: { [index in T[number]]?: string; };
}

class Bar1 implements Foo<["key1", "key2"]> {
  obj = {"key1": "value1"} // OK
}

class Bar2 implements Foo<["key1", "key2"]> {
  obj = {"some-other-key": "value1"} // Error :)
}
```

Comment: OK, that's pretty close! Is it possible to move `["key1", "key2"]` to a reusable variable or type somewhere? I suspect users won't want to repeat the same set of keys over and over.

Comment: Ah, duh, you just make it a type: `type Keys = ["key1", "key2"]`. You can then do `Foo<Keys>`. Thanks!